# Given a few block matrices, get the overall large matrix

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch, reshape, tensor

In short, we are given a 4D tensor `y` of shape `( B // s2, D2 // s1, s1, s2)`, where `y[i,j,...]` represents a matrix of shape (s1,s2). These are the block matrices used to construct the overall large matrix of shape (D2, B), and there are `(B//s2) * (D2 //s1)` such block matrices in total. Here we assume all the numbers involved are integers. I am clear on how to do it using for loops:

```
# y shape ( B // s2, D2 // s1, s1, s2)
result = torch.zeros(D2, B)
for i in range(D2 // s1):
    for j in range(B // s2):
         result[i * s1: (i + 1) * s1, j * s2: (j + 1) * s2] = y[j,i, ...]
```

I know the assignment can be done in parallel. Can we use pytorch built-in functions to eliminate the two for loops?

Answer (score 1):

This is called a fold operation, [`nn.Fold`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Fold.html#fold) and [`F.fold`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.fold.html#torch.nn.functional.fold) are made for this purpose. If you look at the documentation, it reads:

> Combines an array of sliding local blocks into a large containing tensor.
>
> Consider a batched input tensor containing sliding local blocks, *e.g.*, patches of images, of shape `(N,C×∏(kernel_size),L)`, where:
>
> - `N` is batch dimension,
> - `C×∏(kernel_size)` is the number of values within a block (a block has `∏(kernel_size)` spatial locations each containing a `C`-channeled vector),
> - `L` is the total number of blocks.
>
> This is exactly the same specification as the output shape of `Unfold`. This operation combines these local blocks into the large output tensor of shape `(N,C,output_size[0],output_size[1],…)` by summing the overlapping values.

In your case, your input tensor is shaped `(B//s2,D2//s1,s1,s2)`. To get to the specs, you have `L = B//s2 * D2//s1` and kernel `∏(kernel_size) = s1 * s2`. Since the function expects `L` in last position you will need to do some permutation before flattening:

```
y_ = y.permute(2,3,1,0).reshape(s1*s2,-1)
```

Now `y_` is shaped `(s1*s2, B//s2*D2//s1)`. Finally you can apply the fold:

```
F.fold(y_, output_size=(D2,B), kernel_size=(s1,s2), stride=(s1,s2))
```